# wordpress image attachment metadata without generating thumbnails

Tags: wordpress

i want to process all the attachments but without regenerating the thumbnails again. Right now i am using wp_generate_attachment_metadata()..but this takes long time for executing all the post attachments because of thumbanail creations. I just want serialize meta data array for faster execution.

Answer (score 4):

You can write your own version of this function without thumbs generation, take a look here :
http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.1/wp-admin/includes/image.php#L80

For example :

```
function my_generate_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id, $file ) {
    $attachment = get_post( $attachment_id );

    $metadata = array();
    if ( preg_match('!^image/!', get_post_mime_type( $attachment )) && file_is_displayable_image($file) ) {
        $imagesize = getimagesize( $file );
        $metadata['width'] = $imagesize[0];
        $metadata['height'] = $imagesize[1];
        list($uwidth, $uheight) = wp_constrain_dimensions($metadata['width'], $metadata['height'], 128, 96);
        $metadata['hwstring_small'] = "height='$uheight' width='$uwidth'";

        // Make the file path relative to the upload dir
        $metadata['file'] = _wp_relative_upload_path($file);

        // fetch additional metadata from exif/iptc
        $image_meta = wp_read_image_metadata( $file );
        if ( $image_meta )
            $metadata['image_meta'] = $image_meta;
    }

    return apply_filters( 'wp_generate_attachment_metadata', $metadata, $attachment_id );
}
```

Comment: Yes, but is there any other option like passing true/false parameters to the function? i dont want to rewrite the same peice of code.

Comment: Take a look at source, there is no option for that. Answer updated with example

Comment: Thanks but i will miss the $arr['sizes']

Comment: I gave you an example, you should adapt if to fit your needs